# Getting a column based on a record

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

In the input table the values keep changing every week. So, the next week column E would be have A instead of F and at that point I would want the E field.

So, whichever field has A has to be selected but the field having A should be the last field in the table that has an A as a record.

Input Table:

```
A  |  B | C | D | E
A    A    A   A   F
12  32   43  23  2
```

Output :

```
D
A
23
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to normalize your data. You have too much reliance on column order and all sorts of other bad things going on here.

Comment: Normalize in what way?

Comment: Well...are you familiar with database normalization? What you are describing is happening with your data sounds like it needs to be normalized. You are struggling with the query because your data structure is not optimal.

Comment: Dynamically determining which column to SELECT from based on the data in all of the columns. You'll need to hit that table at least twice, once to figure out the column, then once again with the `SELECT <whatever_column_is_the_winner> FROM table;`. It all sounds very wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange I am familiar with it theoretically but not practically. But, i get what you're saying.

Comment: @JNevill Can you give a code or like a prototype?

Comment: So... this table, does it always only have two records in it? If so, how would you identify the record that has the letters in it?  Like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE A='A';`? I would imagine you would have to get that output, analyze each field in a procedure looking for the one that has the highest ordinal (using a variable in a loop) that has value `A`, add that column name to a variable, then construct your second sql statement dynamically using that column name variable. That's a heck of a lot of work to get back a single column of data.

Comment: @JNevill One final question, how can i add ordinal values?

Comment: Perhaps you could (without looping): `SELECT CASE WHEN F='A' THEN 'F' WHEN E='A' THEN 'E' WHEN D='A' THEN 'D'... END as column FROM table WHERE A='A';` to determine the column. Stick that result in a variable and then build your dynamic statement using that. No cursors or other expensive looping, but still ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your data is unnormalized for some reason if you need a logic to get the results you can use this code:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (A varchar(3), B varchar(3),C varchar(3), D varchar(3), E varchar(3))

;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT ColumnName 
                ,ColumnValue
                ,Row_number() 
                   OVER( 
                     partition BY ColumnName 
                     ORDER BY Rn) ResultOrder 
         FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))Rn,a ,b ,c ,d ,e FROM   @table) p 
            UNPIVOT ( ColumnValue 
                    FOR ColumnName IN( a ,b ,c ,d ,e)) AS unpvt), 
     cte1 
     AS (SELECT Ntile(5) 
                  OVER( 
                    ORDER BY ColumnName) ColumnId 
                ,* 
         FROM   cte), 
     cte2 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT Isnull(NULLIF(ColumnId - 1, 0), 5) ColumnId 
                         ,ColumnName 
         FROM   cte1 
         WHERE  ColumnValue = 'F') 
SELECT result 
FROM   (SELECT CASE ColumnId 
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
                 WHEN 2 THEN 'B' 
                 WHEN 3 THEN 'C' 
                 WHEN 4 THEN 'D' 
                 WHEN 5 THEN 'E' 
               END Result 
               ,0  ResultOrder 
        FROM   cte2 
        UNION 
        SELECT ColumnValue 
               ,resultorder 
        FROM   cte1 a 
        WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   cte2 b 
                       WHERE  a.ColumnId = b.ColumnId)) AS R 
ORDER  BY resultorder
```

Result For

```
insert @table VALUES
('A','A','A','A','F')
,('12','32','43','23','2')

A    B    C    D    E
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
A    A    A    A    F
12   32   43   23   2

result
------
D
23
A
```

Result For

```
insert @table VALUES
('F','A','A','A','A')
,('12','32','43','23','2')
A    B    C    D    E
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
F    A    A    A    A
12   32   43   23   2

result
------
E
A
2
```

Explanation:

- **CTE** table does the Unpivot the table and create a row number for order the column name and the value
- **CT1** table creates a group base on column name using the NTILE to create 5 groups
- **CTE2** table get the previous column where the value is equal F
- **The Select** Is complex to translate the ColumnId to ColumnName, if it not necessary,

you can use

```
SELECT ColumnValue Result              
FROM   cte1 a 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM   cte2 b 
WHERE  a.ColumnId = b.ColumnId)

Result
------
A
23

(2 row(s) affected)
```

OR

```
SELECT ColumnValue Result              
FROM   cte1 a 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM   cte2 b 
WHERE  a.ColumnId = b.ColumnId) 
AND a.ResultOrder = 2

Result
------
23

(1 row(s) affected)
```